# How to draw connections between items in a QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I wonder how to draw the lines connecting the items in a `QTreeView` as illustrated in the picture under *Tree Model*. My program will run on different platforms and thus use different styles. Can I guarantee that the items are drawn as desired?

I feel, using style sheets might be problematic because certain styles do not print such lines and using a delagate might lead me into issues of double drawing.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an example in the documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtreeview) showing exactly what you want to achieve using **style sheets**.

Please note that when you use style sheets **QStyleSheetStyle** kicks in, irregardless from the *QStyle* your application is using at the moment. So if you decide to go this way you will override the look and feel of your control the same way, irregardless from the target platform.

If that is a problem, you may consider to use style sheets only for certain platforms. As an example:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_MAC
    myControl->setStyleSheet(":/my_stylesheet_for_mac.qss");
#endif
```

Back to the example in the documentation, it uses a few images containing all the various lines (vertical, horizontal, branch, etc) and the `::branch` subcontrol and its states to determine which image to use.

The result is something like this:

[image: result].

Obviously, you must change the code to show the vline picture instead of the arrows.

As a side node, I may suggest to consider why you want to do this if you are using native styles. If your application has a native look and feel, you should not alter it in any way. That is, if the target platform doesn't render lines to connect tree view items, then you shouldn't add those.

However, if your application is not required to look native across all the target platforms, you may consider using the same style (e.g. *Fusion*) and deliver the same user experience no matter what the platform is.

Comment: Simplest way to redraw arrows - is to pick current `QStyle` from tree control and to override painting of it with [`QProxyStyle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html)